# systemctl: Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory

Tags: debian, dkms

I am trying to install wireless drivers on my Dell Studio 1555 (as per [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#Installation)).

In order to install the drivers the guide asks me to install `dkms`, which I did by running

```
sudo apt-get install dkms
```

Afterwards, the instructions say to enable the service by running `sudo systemctl enable dkms`. However, when I run this command, I get the following:

```
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

I have tried rebooting, with no change. What am I doing wrong?

Running `systemctl status dkms.service` produced the following output:

```
user@debian:~$ sudo systemctl status dkms.service
[sudo] password for user: 
● dkms.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Comment: did you run **sudo systemctl enable dkms** ? can you  edit your question and post the output of **sudo systemctl status dkms.service**?

Comment: dkms isn't a service.   At least it isn't on debian.  Installing *linux-image-\**, *linux-headers-\**, and *\*-dkms* packages trigger dkms updates via their .postinst scripts on debian.

Comment: @LilloX done...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

You're mixing operating systems.

You're following instructions written for Arch Linux on Debian Linux.  Debian Linux packages dkms in a very different way to Arch Linux.  Arch Linux uses a systemd service unit to load/unload DKMS kernel modules.  Debian Linux uses `modprobe.d` files.

Use the doco of the operating system that you are actually using.

### Further reading

- [*bcm43xx*](https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx).  Debian wiki.
- [*wl*](https://wiki.debian.org/wl).  Debian wiki.